Format Mismatch Error when sending video header through WhatsApp API
I'm testing sending media headers through the WhatsApp API. But I keep getting the following error:
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#132012) Parameter format does not match format in the created template",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 132012,
        "error_data": {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "details": "header: Format mismatch, expected VIDEO, received UNKNOWN"
        },
        "fbtrace_id": "AVPT6EiX3RemyP3uv4S36FZ"
    }
}

I'm using a video URL to send the message and confirmed the video is publicly viewable. But I also got the same error when using the video link in the template. I know that there is a Resumable API for uploading the media, but that is not what I'm testing for here.
Any help would be appreciated.
For reference, this is the template:
{
            "name": "vid_test",
            "previous_category": "UTILITY",
            "components": [
                {
                    "type": "HEADER",
                    "format": "VIDEO",
                    "example": {
                        "header_handle": [
                            "https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/380066992_950204086818012_8956032979900394560_n.mp4?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=8b1bef&_nc_ohc=pmivIdgTvrAQ7kNvgEgxK28&_nc_oc=Adg2vVNVfN1TlUWzFmJxHpa830uVJRRCSKsooFiDp0E_AQ7gLbB-RIGSlx8UNvM0cXw&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&oh=01_Q5AaIFBxPaJzBmN9IaDMHWuIw-w8fQX3uHngw2A_qNyhKBVw&oe=666BB20F"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "BODY",
                    "text": "tesing {{1}} and use code {{2}} to get amazing discounts on testing videos.",
                    "example": {
                        "body_text": [
                            [
                                "Message content",
                                "MSG25"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "FOOTER",
                    "text": "Use the buttons below to manage your marketing subscriptions"
                },
                {
                    "type": "BUTTONS",
                    "buttons": [
                        {
                            "type": "QUICK_REPLY",
                            "text": "Unsubscribe from Promos"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "QUICK_REPLY",
                            "text": "Unsubscribe from All"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "language": "en",
            "status": "APPROVED",
            "category": "MARKETING",
            "id": "950180443487043"
        }

And the POST message body:
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
  "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "MY PHONE NUMBER",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "vid_test",
    "language": {
      "code": "en"
    }
  },
  "components": [
    {
      "type": "header",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "VIDEO",
          "video": {
            "Link": "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/006/996/488/mp4/timelapse-full-sunset-free-video.mp4"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Type": "Body",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Var 1"
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Var 2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

